# Laravel checkbox save and update

Tags: laravel

What is the best practice for saving and updating a checkbox in Laravel?

I have set the boolean data type and a default values is 0 in migration file and if i try to save the checkbox i get this error:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column
```

and what about the update method also...

this is my checkbox in view file:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('clothing_supplied', null, isset($event) ? $event->clothing_supplied : 0, ['id' => 'check', 'class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
```

and this is how i update

```
$event->update($request->all());
```

Comment: can you share the code for the `checkbox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$event->clothing_supplied = ($request->get('clothing_supplied') === 'on');
```

This should be added to your controller action or wherever you're updating your model.

This happens because the actual value submitted by the form is the string `on` instead of a boolean value.

Alternatively:

```
$all = $request->all();
$all['clothing_supplied'] = ($request->get('clothing_supplied') === 'on');
$event->update($all);
```

Comment: i get the same error...it should be saved as 0 or 1

Comment: Try casting it as a boolean. I have update my answer.

Comment: maybe this should work $model->clothing_supplied = ($request->get('parameter') === 1);

Comment: BTW Instead of `parameter` you have to use `clothing_supplied`

Comment: what would be equivalent command for this $event->update(clothing_supplied);

Comment: What is `$event`? A model? What's the context where it's being used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129170/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-siannone).

Comment: More elegant (independent of input's value attr):
$all['clothing_supplied'] = intval($request->has('clothing_supplied'));

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$request->replace(array('clothing_supplied' => (bool)$request->input('clothing_supplied')));`

`$event->update($request->all());`

Only edit a single field based on a certain value

`(bool)($request->input('clothing_supplied') == 'on') ? $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 1]) : $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 0]);`

Comment: can i update only one field instead of $request->all()...for example $event->update(only clothing_supplied);

Comment: yeah, try using `$event->update(['clothing_supplied'=>$request->input('clothing_supplied')])`

Comment: well then this would be the best solution `$event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 1]);`

Comment: here you are setting the value to `1`. aren't you going to set the value from the form input?

Comment: i would do something like this: `$request->has('clothing_supplied') ? $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 1]) : $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 0]);` wouldn't that be good?

Comment: `$request->has` will return `true` even if the value is set to `0`. It checks if a given parameter is present or not

Comment: try `(bool)($request->input('clothing_supplied') == 'on') ? $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 1]) : $event->update(['clothing_supplied' => 0]);`

Comment: thanks....i accepted siannones answer because he helped me in chat little more...

Comment: that's ok. happens a lot of time I guess!